# What is my error when finding $e^0$?

Tags: calculus

Consider the Maclaurin series of $e^x$ as follows:
$$(a)~~e^x=\tfrac{x^0}{0!}+ \tfrac{x^1}{1!}+ \tfrac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots$$
$$(b)~~e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{x^n}{n!}$$
Many related books refer the students to the first form $(a)$ to be memorized. Today, a student asked me of what happens while finding $e^0$ by using these two forms. Honestly, I didn’t know how to answer such a question, leaving me ashamed. With $(b)$ he found $1=e^0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\tfrac{0^n}{n!}=0$. I knew that there was something which I could not see. Please make this easy point clear. Thanks!

Comment: We define $0^0=1$ and $0!=1$

Comment: In most formal algebraic contexts we consider $0^0=1$ to avoid having to define special cases when $n=0$ or $x=0$ with formulas involving $x^n$. It is just a convention to make summations shorter. Of course from analysis $0^0$ pov is still undefined.

Comment: Isn't it an indeterminate form?

Comment: Indeterminate form is (the one that you are referring to) a limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)^{g(x)}$, where **the only information that you have** is that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=0$. The $0^0$ here is only a symbol, which you define. You could also think of it as taking limit of $x^0$ as $x\to0$, but observe that here you have more information about $g$. You not only know that $g(x)\to0$. You know that $g(x)=0$.

Comment: @dragonFruit: Thanks for making the light! So, $0^0$ is equal to 1,  but while donig the limits $0^0$ is am indeterminate form. Right?

Comment: @Alireza **Indeterminate form** refers to trying to use one of the [arithmetic properties of the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties) while **only knowing** the limits of the operands and nothing else. It refers to cases in which those formulas simply don't have anything to say, *unless one has more information* besides the limits of the operands.

Answer (score 1):

The first term is $1$.  We have $x^0=1$ and $0!=1$, both by definition.  Thus $e^x=1+o(x)\implies e^0=1$.

Comment: So you assumed $x^0$ to be 1? I put $x=0$ in both sides instead.

Comment: If you look it up, the constant term is $f(a)$.  The expressions $(x-a)^0$ and $0!$ are _defined_ to be $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

The convention adopted for power series and polynomials is that $x^0$ stands for the constant $1$. Therefore $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{0^k}{k!}=\frac{1}{0!}=1$.

Comment: If it is available, give a reference for me. Thanks

Comment: I presume your book, for instance, but I don't know of a specific book that may be considered an "universal" reference for this. Most authors do.

Comment: Thanks for the time.